# Binary formatting in python strings

Tags: python

Is it not possible to do binary formatting in a normal python %-formatted string? For example:

```
>>> "Here is %b" % 4
ValueError: unsupported format character 'b' (0x62) at index 9
```

I know you can using f-strings / format-strings:

```
>>> f"Here is {4:b}"
'Here is 100'

>>> "Here is {num:b}".format(num=4)
'Here is 100'
```

But is there a way to do this with the %-string?

Comment: No, you can format to hexadecimal using `%X` but not binary. The closest you can do is `"Here is %s" % bin(4)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you cannot do binary formatting using %b. You need to use the python bin(number) function which will return binary of that number preceeded by "0b". you could do bin(number)[2:] to slice off 0b.